# Several options using Black-Scholes equation(s)

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, finance

Could someone provide me some information about the modelling of several options at the same time by using Black-Scholes (probably coupled) equations?

Any reference to papers and/or books shall be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks for reading. I am sorry if my question is not properly posed. I am not familiar with the financial terminology. Specifically I am wondering if in finance one has to deal with systems of partial differential equations having the general form
$$
\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2} s^2 \sigma_1^2(s,t) \frac{\partial^2 u_1}{\partial s^2} + s\mu_1 \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial s} = r_1 u_1 + c_{12} u_2,
$$
$$
\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2} s^2 \sigma_2^2(s,t) \frac{\partial^2 u_2}{\partial s^2} + s\mu_2 \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial s} = r_2 u_2 + c_{21} u_1,
$$
where the $c_{12}$ and $c_{21}$ act as coupling coefficients.

Thanks in advance again.

Comment: This question is best placed on [quant.stackexchange](http://quant.stackexchange.com/)- if at all.

Comment: Before you ask the question on quant.SE, you better clarify what is "several options at the same time". A basket option (an option on a basket of underliers),  some sort of [rainbow options] (an option on the best or worst of $n$ assets) or something else.

Comment: you need to provide more background information: how are those equations come up.